# Prevent Event Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Gridview. I and populating two dynamic text box for each cell inside it. User will enter the arriving time in first textbox and the arriving + 9 hours will be added and display in second textbox. I have written event handler where i am calculating exit time. the event handler is working fine but I need to event handler will fire for first Cell only. How to prevent event handler for rest of the textbox.

Comment: please include event binding and handling code

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide code but this is a general example.

```
 private bool _isFirst = true;
 private void CellEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if (!_isFirst) return;

      // code
      _isFirst = false;
 }
```

You could also unbind the event handler

```
 private void CellEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      // your code here
      textBox.Click -= CellEventHandler;
 }
```

Comment: In your last example - remember to rebind the event when you are done updating behinds its back :)